# Linux sed, how to delete the rest of the word?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Suppose I have **text.txt**:

```
342423423423 - 'namefile.jpg' saved (2423423kb/2423423kb)
```

I can use

```
sed 's/^.*- //' text.txt
```

the output will be:

```
'namefile.jpg' saved (2423423kb/2423423kb)
```

it will get rid the text at the beginning of that `namefile.jpg`, but what if I also want to get rid the rest of it ? I want the output to be like this:

```
'namefile.jpg'
```

What sed pattern should I use? Please note that after the 'namefile.jpg' the text isn't always the same. It changes from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use capturing groups.

```
sed 's/^.*- \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/' text.txt
```

OR

```
sed 's/^.*- //;s/ .*//' file
```

- `^.*-` regex matches all the characters from the start upto `-`. And the first command replaces all the matches characters with an empty string.
- `.*` Now from the resultant string, this regex would match all the characters from the first space upto the last. Replacing those characters with an empty string will gave you the desired output.

Example:

```
$ echo "342423423423 - 'namefile.jpg' saved (2423423kb/2423423kb" | sed 's/^.*- \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'
'namefile.jpg'
$ echo "342423423423 - 'namefile.jpg' saved (2423423kb/2423423kb" | sed 's/^.*- //;s/ .*//'
'namefile.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with **awk:**

```
echo "342423423423 - 'namefile.jpg' saved (2423423kb/2423423kb)" | awk '{print $3}'
```

Default delimiter for `awk` is space. Just print the 3rd field.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way also

```
sed "s/.*\('.*'\).*/\1/" FileName
```

**Output :**

```
'namefile.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not `sed` but show how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F\' '{print $2}' text.txt
namefile.jpg
```

or if you like to have the single quotes.

```
awk -F\' '{print FS$2FS}' text.txt
'namefile.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `cut` command

```
cut -d ' ' -f3 text.txt
```

or you can also use this,

```
sed 's/^.*- //' text.txt|cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Both will give you this **Output**:

```
'namefile.jpg'
```